# Openlayers - get the center point of a Linesting on the line

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to show the popup at the center point of a linestring, for now I've used

```js
    popup.show(e.search.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate(), e.search);
```

but so i capture the first coordinate, is there a way to capture the center point of a linestring that is on the linestring?

Thank you

All code

```js
    if (e.search.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point' || e.search.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiPoint') {
    popup.show(e.search.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate(), e.search);
    } if (e.search.getGeometry().getType() === 'Polygon' || e.search.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiPolygon') {
    popup.show(e.search.getGeometry().getInteriorPoints().getFirstCoordinate(), e.search);
    }   if (e.search.getGeometry().getType() === 'LineString' || e.search.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiLineString') {
    popup.show(e.search.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate(), e.search);
    }
```

Comment: `e.search.getGeometry().getCoordinateAt(0.5)`  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_LineString-LineString.html#getCoordinateAt

Comment: In case of MultiLineString I understand that I have to use `getCoordinateAtM`, but I don't understand how to use it, can you help me? An example of geojson [here](https://www.opengis.it/ente/furlo/layers/n440_68km_h423m_500.js)

Comment: `getCoordinateAtM` is for 3 or 4 dimensional geometries with time (XYM or XYZM layout).  Otherwise you can get the center point of one of the component LineStrings, e.g. `geometry.getLineString(0).getCoordinateAt(0.5)`

Comment: Thanks Mike, your support is indispensable.